# Angular conversion from FormBuilder. style to FormGroup. How to create Formarray?

Tags: angular, formgroups, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to get some code that works and uses FormBuilder style to work with my FormGroup style component. I need to add a child component that contains a collection. So The working version has:

```
 createFormGroup(order: Order): FormGroup {
    const  group = this.fb.group({
        id: [order.id],
        invoiceNumber: [order.invoiceNumber, Validators.required],
        customerName: [order.customerName, Validators.required],
        total: [order.total],
        orderItems: this.fb.array([])
    });

    order.orderItems.forEach(x => {
        var formArray = group.controls.orderItems as FormArray;
        formArray.push(this.createOrderItem(x));
    });

    return group;
}
```

And my version has

```
 this.orderForm = new FormGroup({
  'reqDetails': new FormGroup({
    'reqDesc': new FormControl(this.order.reqDesc, Validators.required),
    'orderNumber': new FormControl(this.order.orderNumber),
    'selectedVendorId': new FormControl(this.order.orderVendorId)
  }),
  'itemsDetails': new FormGroup({
    'isItPurchase': new FormControl(this.order.isItPurchase),
    'orderItems' : new FormArray(this.orderItems)
  })
});
```

Why do I get the error

```
"message": "Argument of type 'OrderItem[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl[]'.\n  Type 'OrderItem' is missing the following properties from type 'AbstractControl': validator, asyncValidator, _parent, _asyncValidationSubscription, and 44 more.",
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this.orderItems` should return and array of [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

Like your working example

```js
order.orderItems.forEach(x => {
  var formArray = group.controls.orderItems as FormArray;
  formArray.push(this.createOrderItem(x)); // <-- here is returning array of FormControl
});
```

Comment: How do I do that with the new syntax?